# Jmespath setting the jmespath expr dynamically

Tags: jmespath

I am using jmespath as follows

```py
data = {
    "value": [
        {
            "datasetId": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
            "id": "5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "name": "SalesMarketing2",
            "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48/reports/5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715&groupId=f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48",
        },
        {
            "datasetId": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
            "id": "5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "name": "SalesMarketing3",
            "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48/reports/5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715&groupId=f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48",
        },
    ]
}
```

And setting the jmespath expr dynamically as:

```py
report= 'SalesMarketing3'
```

```
jmespath.search(f"'value[?name == {report}]'", data)
```

Instead of getting the dictionary corresponding to "SalesMarketing3", I am getting output as follows, Am I missing something?

> 'value[?name == SalesMarketing3]'

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that you have to search on the **string** or **raw string literal** `SalesMarketing3`.
In JMESPath:

- A string is delimited by single quotes: `'SalesMarketing3'`
- A raw string literal is delimited by backticks: `` `SalesMarketing3` ``

Given *example.py*:

```py
import jmespath

data = {
    "value": [
        {
            "datasetId": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
            "id": "5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "name": "SalesMarketing2",
            "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48/reports/5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715&groupId=f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48",
        },
        {
            "datasetId": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
            "id": "5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "name": "SalesMarketing3",
            "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48/reports/5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
            "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715&groupId=f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48",
        },
    ]
}
report = 'SalesMarketing3'

print(jmespath.search(f"value[?name == `{report}`]", data))
## Another equivalent is:
# print(jmespath.search(f"value[?name == '{report}']", data))
```

This gives the expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "datasetId": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
    "id": "5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
    "name": "SalesMarketing3",
    "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48/reports/5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715",
    "embedUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=5b218778-e7a5-4d73-8187-f10824047715&groupId=f089354e-8366-4e18-aea3-4cb4a3a50b48"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use J**MESPath Terminal** to interactively write complex queries - it's really useful when you're stuck with JMESPath. You can find more about the tool here:
https://www.doaws.pl/blog/2021-12-05-how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes/how-to-master-aws-cli-in-15-minutes